# Chrome 101 reduces the information in the User Agent string - Jquery UI response

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, navigator

My current Chrome browser 96.0.4664.45 is showing this alert message when visiting bookingaround.com :

> Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform
> A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. Starting in Chrome 101, the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be reduced.
> To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection, progressive enhancement, or migrate to navigator.userAgentData.
> Note that for performance reasons, only the first access to one of the properties is shown.
> 1 source
> ScriptResource.axd:1

This is because of Jquery UI v1.12.1 which employes navigator.userAgent. Unfortunately the new version 1.13.0 seems to also use this method.
Can someone predict what behavior should I expect from the site using Jquery UI v1.13.0 after installing Chrome v.101? How to know if Jquery UI will follow Chrome's suggestions in its new releases?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery's GitHub Issue 2026](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/issues/2026) says:

> The warnings are caused by the following code: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.13.0/ui/ie.js#L17. It was added to detect IE and it's deprecated anyway. The Chrome DevTools warning is harmless; since the code is only used to detect IE, no changes Chrome will make to its User Agent will cause any issues unless they change their UA to look like the one used by old IE - which they won't do as it'd break lots of sites in Chrome.